# JSF issue about space

Tags: jsf

I am a green bird in JSF, now I was puzzled by the text of it.

when I assign the value of the outputText with multi-spaces, the result shown in IE has only one space.

ex: the code is like

```
<h:outputText id="name" value="aa (multi-spaces here)  bbb" ></h:outputText>
```

the result text shown in IE is "aa bbb"

can anyone tell me why the spaces disappear without trace?

Comment: Rightclick page and *View Source*. The spaces are still there. It's just the way how browser (is supposed to) interpret the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is defined by the HTML spec:

> For all HTML elements except `PRE`, sequences of white space separate "words" (we use the term "word" here to mean "sequences of non-white space characters"). When formatting text, user agents should identify these words and lay them out according to the conventions of the particular written language (script) and target medium.

*Note that if you are using XHTML, there are some differences in how [attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.7) and the [code point U+000C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_15) are handled.*

For most text, sequences of white space are not rendered any differently from a single space.

---

Since this is for a `outputText` control, you can use a one-way converter for a no-break space solution:

```
package myconverters;
// imports

public class SpacePreserver implements Converter {
  private static final char NO_BREAK_SPACE = '\u00A0';

  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
      Object value) {
    if (component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Cannot use SpacePreserver converter on editable controls.");
    }
    return value == null ? null : value.toString().replace(' ', NO_BREAK_SPACE);
  }

  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
      String value) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Output converter only");
  }
}
```

This can be defined (among other ways) using a faces-config.xml entry:

```
<converter>
  <converter-id>spacePreserver</converter-id>
  <converter-class>myconverters.SpacePreserver</converter-class>
</converter>
```

You can then add this to your output control:

```
<h:outputText id="text1" value="a   b c" converter="spacePreserver" />
```

*This code was tested using JSF 1.1 with a UTF-8 encoded JSP 2.0 view. Note that use of a no-break space will prohibit line-wrapping.*

Comment: Is there any approach to avoid that? As I want to get the complete string that we typed not the formatted one

Comment: You could also use `&nbsp;` as a whitespace. This won't collapse when used multiple times.

Comment: The case is, I need to validate the input string and rerender the inputText. If the input string contains multi-spaces, it will be displayed as one space after validating. So &nbsp can not work here.

Comment: I hava tried the <pre> element and CSS white-space, but nothing work on the <h:inputText> tag...

Comment: There is no way to avoid this. This is specific to HTML. There is no way to get it to work on input elements other than textarea. You might want to use an `<h:inputTextarea>` with 1 row and some JavaScript which blocks the [Enter] key and some CSS to hide the scrollbars. There is not really JSF-specific solution (because this is a pure HTML matter).

Comment: The converter works! It's Wonderful, thank you Dowell and thanks everyone here!